# Winform textbox thousand seperator for money?

Tags: string, winforms, textbox, format

I need to enter value for money in txtMoney (textbox),I want when LostFocus, it will be add thousand seperator. My money look like 1.500, 2.000.000,..., they are integer only, can divide by 100.
How can I do it?

void txtMoney_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private readonly CultureInfo _provider = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("vi-VN");
    private decimal ParseMoney
    {
        get { return decimal.Parse(txtMoney.Text, _provider); }
    }

    private string FormatMoney
    {
        get { return string.Format(_provider, "{0:##,###}", ParseMoney); }
    }

    private void txtMoney_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtMoney.Text = FormatMoney;
    }
```

The example is for Vietnamese format.

More information: [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: After format the string was change, How can I re-parse the text to decimal or int? Do I need to remove "." char from the string manually

Comment: Please see my edit. More information [Parsing Numeric Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w(v=vs.110).aspx)